# joiner data and index cache

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

Assuming that the Master Pipeline has 5 fields, two of which are part of the join condition and that all fields are connected downstream to the next transformation, how many fields are in the index and data cache files?

I am confused in the below 2 answers. Please Check.

> 5 fields are in the index cache and 3 fields in the data cache.
>
> OR
>
> 2 fields are in the index cache and 3 fields in the data cache.

Answer (score 1):

Answer 2 is correct. So index cache holds columns that are used in join condition  and all output columns to data cache. Sequence wise, first it populates detail data into cache and then compares master data with that details data. Did some testing and this is the result -

- With 2 join conditions and 2 output ports session log result -
  The index cache size that would hold [99] input rows from the master for [JNR_Level1], in memory, is [121856] bytes
  The data cache size that would hold [99] input rows from the master for [JNR_Level1], in memory, is [62568] bytes
- With 2 join condition 1 output ports session log result -
  The index cache size that would hold [99] input rows from the master for [JNR_Level1], in memory, is [121856] bytes
  The data cache size that would hold [99] input rows from the master for [JNR_Level1], in memory, is [1608] bytes
- With 1 join condition and 4 output  ports session log result -
  The index cache size that would hold [99] input rows from the master for [JNR_Level1], in memory, is [61952] bytes
  The data cache size that would hold [99] input rows from the master for [JNR_Level1], in memory, is [183744] bytes

Koushik